# How to implement drag drop of CSV files into C# WPF and using the data in a datatable?

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, datatable

I've spent some time searching online for something that might help me but couldn't find exactly what I need. I found lots of examples with Windows forms but not with WPF.

I've got an army of CSV files. Each files contains only one datasheet, and the sheet only contains two columns. First column contains headers (the same for each CSV file) and the second column contains data. I'm trying to write something where the user can drag up to 5 CSV files into an area on the form and the application visualizes the first column and then up to 5 columns of data next to each other for comparison.

Anyone who can point me in the right direction will be much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't have anything handy in the way of easily getting the CSV data to the database - perhaps someone else will drop in. Adding support for drag'n'drop is a fairly simple matter of setting AllowDrop to true on the target container and then implementing its Drop event handler along the lines of

```
        private void FilesDropped(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
            {

                string[] droppedFilePaths = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 3 parts to this problem:

1. Enabling Drag & Drop support in your app (see 500 - Internal Server Error's answer for this)
2. Reading the selected CSV files. For this you might check out [Mike Stall's DataTable project on Github](https://github.com/MikeStall/DataTable)
3. Displaying a DataGrid in WPF bound to the data returned in step 2.
   For step three, these prior SO questions might be of value to you:

[Generating columns dynamically in the WPF DataGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564827/generating-columns-dynamically-in-the-wpf-datagrid)

[WPF DataGrid Good Tutorials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5572921/wpf-datagrid-good-tutorials)

[Binding WPF DataGrid to DataTable using TemplateColumns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677446/binding-wpf-datagrid-to-datatable-using-templatecolumns)

Comment: Thanks Tim. It's the first time I see the DataTable Project from Github and it looks like it will help me a lot. I can do the other parts (the drag-drop maybe I add later) but it looks like it's going to be the CSV handling and import into datatable which may give me the most headache.